# Add more files option in Contact 7 or Gravity forms

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I need multiple files uploaded as per design.
Here is the screenshot.
[image]
But I search it on contact 7 and gravity form. But not found. Anybody any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For WP Contact Form 7 :

Add some file uploading fields :

```
<p class="hide">[file file-01]</p>
<p class="hide">[file file-02]<a class="del_file" href="#">Delete</a></p>
<p class="hide">[file file-03]<a class="del_file" href="#">Delete</a></p>

<a href="#" class="add_file">Add file </a>
```

Next, add this script (You need JQuery)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    //hide all inputs except the first one
    $('p.hide').not(':eq(0)').hide();

    //functionality for add-file link
    $('a.add_file').on('click', function(e){
      //show by click the first one from hidden inputs
      $('p.hide:not(:visible):first').show('slow');
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    //functionality for del-file link
    $('a.del_file').on('click', function(e){
      //var init
      var input_parent = $(this).parent();
      var input_wrap = input_parent.find('span');
      //reset field value
      input_wrap.html(input_wrap.html());
      //hide by click
      input_parent.hide('slow');
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

Now you can hide and show your fields !